# How to edit primary business profile on Twilio

Tags: twilio, sms, filtering, message

How does one edit Primary Business Profile on Twilio.  I cannot sent sms as my primary business profile is not correct and I cant find how to edit it. I have written to support at Twilio and nothing back yet.

Thanks

I first put my Social Security number in for the EINS and that didnt work.... So I think that is the issue.  I now have what I believe the correct EINS.